# AttributeError: 'tkapp' object has no attribute 'var'

Tags: python, checkbox, tkinter, boolean, output

I am trying to write a program so every time the checkbox is clicked it prints "hello world to the output file".

I've got it printing the stuff in the entry widgets so far but how do I get the state of the checkbox so when its click it prints "hello world" and when its not clicked it does nothing?

```
import Tkinter as Tk
from Tkinter import StringVar

class SampleApp(Tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self):
        Tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self.button = Tk.Button(self, text="Get", command=self.on_button)
        self.button.pack()

        labelText=StringVar()
        labelText.set(" First Name")
        labelDir=Tk.Label(self, textvariable=labelText, height=1)
        labelDir.pack()

        directory=StringVar(None)
        self.can_fname =Tk.Entry(self,textvariable=directory,width=50)
        self.can_fname .pack()

        labelText=StringVar()
        labelText.set(" Last Name")
        labelDir=Tk.Label(self, textvariable=labelText, height=1)
        labelDir.pack()

        directory=StringVar(None)
        self.can_lname =Tk.Entry(self,textvariable=directory,width=50)
        self.can_lname .pack()

        var = Tk.IntVar()
        cb = Tk.Checkbutton(self, text="here", variable=var)
        cb.pack()

    def on_button(self):
      if self.var.get():
           print "the lights are on"
      else:
           print "the lights are off"

      a=self.can_fname.get()
      b='hello %s' %(a)

      with open('filename.txt', 'w') as myfile:
          myfile.write(b)


app = SampleApp()
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Have you read the documentation on how to get the value from a `IntVar`?

Comment: yes you use the get method don't you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`var` is a local variable to the `__init__` method or constructor. You are basically receiving the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'tkapp' object has no attribute 'var'
```

because `var` is garbage collected once the `__init__` method has terminated its execution. You should change `var` to `self.var`, in order to make it a field (property) of the class.